# Smooth output from root.bind key

Tags: python, tkinter, input

If you use Root.bind to get a key input and add a function it will execute, it will execute it, make a small pause, and then keep rapidly executing it but how to do it without it making a pause, might work if there is a way to detect if it was clicked (not released) and then start executing it and when the button is lifted it will stop executing it? (not using another import, it dont work idk why)

```
from tkinter import *

A = 0

def fun(event):
    global A
    if event.keysym == 'space':
        A += 1
        print(A)

root = Tk()

root.bind("<Key>", fun)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Are you just pressing and holding a single key? That's probably the OS or keyboard doing auto-repeat. tkinter has no control over that. This sounds like it might be an [xy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) problem. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but if you only care about the `space` key you can use `'<Key-space>'` in your binding instead of just `'<Key>'`. That way your bound function won't needlessly fire on every single keypress and you won't need `if event.keysym == 'space'`. This won't ignore key repeats from a held key, however. An easy way to do that is to use `'<KeyRelease-space>'` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand the question.  You want to press and hold the space bar and have something executing while the bar is held down and stop once you release the key.

The `<Key>` binding detects key down and then key down for every repeat.

The `<KeyRelease>` binding detects a key release for each key repeat and when the key is actually released.

In the code below `fun_on` executes after each `Key` event and `fun_off` after each `KeyRelease` event.  The `on_after` function in `fun_off` is cancelled if `fun_on` runs before the time expires.

```
import tkinter as tk

A = 0
cycle = False

def fun_off( event ):
    global timer

    def on_after():
        """ This executes 1 ms after it's triggered.
        If a <Key> event is detected during the millisecond it's cancelled.
        See fun_on """
        global A, cycle
        A = 0
        cycle = False

    timer = root.after( 1, on_after ) # More milliseconds may be
                                      # needed for some hardware

def do_cycle(): # This executes as long as cycle is True
    global A
    if cycle: 
        A += 1
        print( A )
        root.after( 10, do_cycle )  # Set ms delay as required.

def fun_on(event):
    """ Cancels the after ID from fun_off. 
        My auto repeat executes key down 0.1 ms after key up.
        This will cancel the after function unless the key is actually released"""
    global cycle

    root.after_cancel( timer )
    if not cycle:
        cycle = True
        do_cycle()

root = tk.Tk()

timer = root.after( 0, lambda: None ) # Makes timer a validafter id. 

root.bind( "<KeyRelease-space>", fun_off )
root.bind( "<Key-space>", fun_on )

root.mainloop()
```